# How to search multiple words in a string using Regular expression using Python

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to read only files from a location which has no "test" and "dummy" in the file name by using regular expression.

For Example the file path has below files.

```
file1.csv
file2.txt
20170811_test_1.dat
1_dummy_20170811.dat
```

Here I need to find file1.csv and file2.txt and exclude all other files which has test or dummy (can be of any case lower/upper).

Comment: So, Python or C#?

Comment: check this link out -  https://superuser.com/questions/903168/how-should-i-write-a-regex-to-match-a-specific-word

Comment: There are usually core methods that allow you to do basic searches for a substring. In Python you can do [str.find()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
^(?!.*test|.*dummy).*$
```

^ : declaring the begining of the line

?! : doesn't contain test OR (|) dummy, even not at the begining (.*)

.* : match all characters

$ : declaring the end of the line